# Progressive Download of MP3 file (streaming and downloading) - IPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, streaming, mp3, progressive-download

Is it possible to stream while saving an MP3 file from a network resource? Also - once an MP3 is downloaded, how can we add it to iTunes on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of streaming, you can do an HTML5 based solution, especially would recommend jPlayer (www.jplayer.org).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm the author, I just wanted to add a bit of help to anyone who was thinking of going down this road since no one else was answering.